# Google Sheets: Use Apps Script to automatically order rows of data based on dropdown value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script to auto-sort rows of data based on the item selected in the dropdown but it's not working. Can anyone figure out why?

```
    function onEdit(e) {
      
      const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();

      var ordering = {
      "Approved":1, //move to the top
      "Accept": 2,
      "Hold": 3,
      "Decline": 4, //move to the bottom
      };
    
      var compareIndex = 13;
      var range = as.getRange(4,1,as.getLastRow(),as[0].length);
      var values = range.getValues();
    
      values.sort(function(a,b){
        return ordering[[a][compareIndex]] - ordering[[b][compareIndex]];
      });
      range.setValues(values);
    }
```

Here is what the sheet looks like:

[image]

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TK-HIr2_ldXSgxnrj5mQZH4PEhOMQBVV/view?usp=sharing) is a screen recording of what I want the behavior to look like...I got it working for "Decline" to move to the bottom but can't get the others to sort in the correct order.

Alternatively, here is a screenshot of what I want the end result to look like.

[image]

The goal is to have rows of data move to the appropriate position based on the Status selected from the dropdown (Column M). "Decline" would move to the bottom while "Approved would move to the top - "Accept" and "Hold" would be between those, in the order shown in the script.

To add another layer - I would ideally also want any dropdowns which have nothing selected to stay at the top of the sheet (with any row with a selected value from the dropdown to be sorted below) and I would like each category (i.e., Approved) to be sorted by date (Column A) with the most recent date at the top of each Status group.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: In your showing image is the sample input situation? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample output situation as the image? And, what is `as` in your script?

Comment: @Tanaike I updated my post with another screenshot, a screen recording and added in the line in the script that defines as

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. When I saw your updated script, it seems that `as` is `const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();`. In this case, I think that an error occurs at `as[0].length` of `var range = as.getRange(4,1,as.getLastRow(),as[0].length);`. Is this error related to your current issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your updated script, it seems that `as` is `const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();`. In this case, I think that an error occurs at `as[0].length` of `var range = as.getRange(4,1,as.getLastRow(),as[0].length);`.
- If `values` of `var values = range.getValues();` is correct values of your data range, I think that `ordering[[a][compareIndex]] - ordering[[b][compareIndex]]` shoud be `ordering[a[compareIndex - 1]] - ordering[b[compareIndex - 1]]`. But, from your sample output situation, if you want to put the empty rows to the above of the data, it should be `(ordering[a[compareIndex - 1]] || 0) - (ordering[b[compareIndex - 1]] || 0)`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var compareIndex = 13;
  // if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1" || e.range.columnStart != compareIndex || e.range.rowStart < 4) return; // If you want to restrict the edited cells, please use this. At that time, please set the sheet name.
  var ordering = {
    "Approved": 1, //move to the top
    "Accept": 2,
    "Hold": 3,
    "Decline": 4, //move to the bottom
  };
  var range = sheet.getRange(4, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 3, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var values = range.getValues();
  values.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (ordering[a[compareIndex - 1]] || 0) - (ordering[b[compareIndex - 1]] || 0);
  });
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

- If you want to put the empty rows to the below of the data, please modify `return (ordering[a[compareIndex - 1]] || 0) - (ordering[b[compareIndex - 1]] || 0);` to `return (ordering[a[compareIndex - 1]] || 5) - (ordering[b[compareIndex - 1]] || 5);`.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks Tanaike! I am also trying to sort by edit date (descending) within each of the sorted Status groups...I tried to add ,{column: 1, ascending: false}) before the ); in the line above the setValues line but it's not sorting by the date column. Would you be able to help with this? Thanks!

Comment: @allison Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `I am also trying to sort by edit date (descending) within each of the sorted Status groups...I tried to add ,{column: 1, ascending: false}) before the ); in the line above the setValues line but it's not sorting by the date column. Would you be able to help with this?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current script from `I tried to add`.

Comment: that was exactly what I needed. I wasn't putting the range.sort in the right part of the script. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @allison Thank you for replying. I'm glad your new question was also resolved.

Answer (score 1):

#### Sorting Rows

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'SheetName' && e.range.columnStart == 13 && e.range.rowStart > 3) {
    //e.source.toast('Sorting')
    const oA = ["Approve", "Accept", "Hold", "Decline",""];
    vs = sh.getRange(4,1,sh.getLastRow() - 3, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    vs.sort((a,b) => {
      let vA = oA.indexOf(a[12]);
      let vB = oA.indexOf(b[12]);
      return vA - vB;
    });
  }
  sh.getRange(4,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  //e.source.toast('Done');
}
```

- [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)