# Google Sheets: Use Apps Script to automatically sort the sheet based on dropdown value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script to auto-sort rows in ascending order based on the item selected in the dropdown in column 2. Instead, what I need is for the rows to sort in a specific order:

1. "Final Phase"
2. "In Progress"
3. "Delayed Pending"
4. "Suspended"
5. "Cancelled"
6. "Proposed"
7. "Completed"

(it's for tracking projects to completion, so it makes sense for it to be in this order only)

Here's the code I have that works perfectly for ascending order (but is not exactly what I need):

```
function autoSort(){
  
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Testing")
const range = ws.getRange(3,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,14)

range.sort({column: 2, ascending: true})
}

function onEdit(e){

const row = e.range.getRow()
const column = e.range.getColumn()

if(!(column === 2 && row >=2)) return

autoSort()

}
```

I made sure to leave one blank row at the bottom

[image]

I've been trying to get this to work for my spreadsheet since yesterday. Based off of code from this [-QUESTION-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71432345/google-sheets-use-apps-script-to-automatically-order-rows-of-data-based-on-drop)

But I keep getting errors:

```
function onEdit(e) {
const range = ws.getRange(3,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,14)
  var compareIndex = 2;
  // if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Test1" || e.range.columnStart != compareIndex || e.range.rowStart < 3) return; // If you want to restrict the edited cells, please use this. At that time, please set the sheet name.
  var ordering = {
    "In Progress": 1, //move to the top
    "Final Phase": 2,
    "Delayed Pending": 3,
    "Suspended": 4,
    "Cancelled": 5,
    "Proposed": 6,
    "Completed": 7, //move to the bottom
  };
  vs = sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var values = range.getValues();
  values.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (ordering[a[compareIndex - 1]] || 0) - (ordering[b[compareIndex - 1]] || 0);
  });
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

I also experimented with this code but it doesnt work either:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Test1' && e.range.columnStart == 14 && e.range.rowStart > 3) {
    //e.source.toast('Sorting')
    const oA = ["In Progress", "Final Phase", "Delayed Pending", "Suspended", "Cancelled", "Poposed", "Completed",""];
    vs = sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    vs.sort((a,b) => {
      let vA = oA.indexOf(a[12]);
      let vB = oA.indexOf(b[12]);
      return vA - vB;
    });
  }
  sh.getRange(3,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  //e.source.toast('Done');
}
```

Is there anyone who can provide me with the code so I can understand what I need to do. I'm learning. Thanks!
[image: ERROR IMAGE]
[image: DEBUG IMAGE, I don't know what this means or how to fix it]

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this:

```
vs.sort((a,b) => {
  let vA = oA.indexOf(a[12]);
  let vB = oA.indexOf(b[12]);
  return vA - vB;
```

be this:

```
 vs.sort((a,b) => {
  let vA = oA.indexOf(a[1]);
  let vB = oA.indexOf(b[1]);
  return vA - vB;
```

and this is sorting a blank row

`vs = sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();`

because your number of rows is incorrect

A simple example of sorting a sheet on dropdown values in column2

Code:

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const list = [... new Set(sh.getRange(2, 2, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat())]
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().sort((a, b) => {
    return list.indexOf(a[1]) - list.indexOf(b[1])
  })
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
  sh.getRange(2, sh.getLastColumn() + 2, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Data:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 15 | A | 11 | 24 | 7 | 15 | 7 | 5 | 9 |  | 15 | A | 11 | 24 | 7 | 15 | 7 | 5 | 9 |
| 3 | 8 | B | 18 | 16 | 3 | 19 | 4 | 15 | 18 |  | 3 | A | 0 | 14 | 13 | 8 | 5 | 11 | 11 |
| 4 | 15 | C | 9 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 2 | 0 |  | 4 | A | 2 | 2 | 21 | 16 | 4 | 13 | 11 |
| 5 | 22 | D | 4 | 15 | 19 | 14 | 20 | 11 | 4 |  | 13 | A | 22 | 13 | 24 | 9 | 23 | 18 | 16 |
| 6 | 3 | E | 13 | 3 | 15 | 1 | 24 | 6 | 4 |  | 12 | A | 3 | 7 | 3 | 24 | 6 | 9 | 16 |
| 7 | 3 | A | 0 | 14 | 13 | 8 | 5 | 11 | 11 |  | 8 | B | 18 | 16 | 3 | 19 | 4 | 15 | 18 |
| 8 | 24 | B | 9 | 6 | 18 | 5 | 3 | 21 | 14 |  | 24 | B | 9 | 6 | 18 | 5 | 3 | 21 | 14 |
| 9 | 16 | C | 7 | 16 | 20 | 10 | 15 | 17 | 14 |  | 16 | B | 1 | 2 | 2 | 7 | 10 | 1 | 14 |
| 10 | 13 | D | 10 | 5 | 9 | 22 | 4 | 17 | 10 |  | 23 | B | 17 | 18 | 21 | 21 | 4 | 13 | 2 |
| 11 | 8 | E | 13 | 19 | 1 | 4 | 22 | 3 | 14 |  | 20 | B | 24 | 14 | 16 | 1 | 13 | 5 | 12 |
| 12 | 4 | A | 2 | 2 | 21 | 16 | 4 | 13 | 11 |  | 15 | C | 9 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 2 | 0 |
| 13 | 16 | B | 1 | 2 | 2 | 7 | 10 | 1 | 14 |  | 16 | C | 7 | 16 | 20 | 10 | 15 | 17 | 14 |
| 14 | 13 | C | 10 | 21 | 22 | 18 | 22 | 3 | 3 |  | 13 | C | 10 | 21 | 22 | 18 | 22 | 3 | 3 |
| 15 | 11 | D | 19 | 0 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 1 |  | 10 | C | 1 | 17 | 15 | 18 | 14 | 15 | 11 |
| 16 | 5 | E | 8 | 22 | 16 | 0 | 16 | 19 | 6 |  | 4 | C | 8 | 13 | 7 | 1 | 4 | 10 | 13 |
| 17 | 13 | A | 22 | 13 | 24 | 9 | 23 | 18 | 16 |  | 22 | D | 4 | 15 | 19 | 14 | 20 | 11 | 4 |
| 18 | 23 | B | 17 | 18 | 21 | 21 | 4 | 13 | 2 |  | 13 | D | 10 | 5 | 9 | 22 | 4 | 17 | 10 |
| 19 | 10 | C | 1 | 17 | 15 | 18 | 14 | 15 | 11 |  | 11 | D | 19 | 0 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 20 | 21 | D | 0 | 3 | 18 | 15 | 9 | 2 | 4 |  | 21 | D | 0 | 3 | 18 | 15 | 9 | 2 | 4 |
| 21 | 23 | E | 7 | 17 | 24 | 8 | 6 | 23 | 13 |  | 2 | D | 2 | 0 | 19 | 2 | 13 | 10 | 6 |
| 22 | 12 | A | 3 | 7 | 3 | 24 | 6 | 9 | 16 |  | 3 | E | 13 | 3 | 15 | 1 | 24 | 6 | 4 |
| 23 | 20 | B | 24 | 14 | 16 | 1 | 13 | 5 | 12 |  | 8 | E | 13 | 19 | 1 | 4 | 22 | 3 | 14 |
| 24 | 4 | C | 8 | 13 | 7 | 1 | 4 | 10 | 13 |  | 5 | E | 8 | 22 | 16 | 0 | 16 | 19 | 6 |
| 25 | 2 | D | 2 | 0 | 19 | 2 | 13 | 10 | 6 |  | 23 | E | 7 | 17 | 24 | 8 | 6 | 23 | 13 |
| 26 | 0 | E | 7 | 15 | 20 | 20 | 2 | 22 | 8 |  | 0 | E | 7 | 15 | 20 | 20 | 2 | 22 | 8 |

The sorted data is posted just to the right of the original data

Comment: @DW I apologize for being discouraging I don't really mean to.  Most of the time I try to avoid saying much of anything but sometimes I forget. I'll keep my comments to the minimum in the future.

Comment: Thanks so much for saying so and for removing your previous comment. I'll keep working on this. So far, when I run my scripts from the editor they have always worked and executed fine, but this one is just tricky for me (though it's probably something you can do in your sleep). We all start somewhere. I'll eventually get it.  Wishing you all the best!

Answer (score 0):

I DID IT, After working on this for a few days...This sorted my sheet in the way I wanted it to be ordered:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Testing")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Testing' && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart > 3) {
    //e.source.toast('Sorting')
    const oA = ["Final Phase", "In Progress", "Delayed Pending", "Suspended", "Cancelled", "Proposed", "Completed", ""];
    vs = sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    vs.sort((a,b) => {
      let vA = oA.indexOf(a[1]);
      let vB = oA.indexOf(b[1]);
      return vA - vB;
    });
  }
  sh.getRange(3,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  //e.source.toast('Done');
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).